# SpriteBuilder CCButton stretched images?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

In spritebuilder, the tool to create UI along with cocos2d, how come whenever I try to add a background image to a CCButton, it appears stretched or altered in some way?

It is hard to explain but after fiddling with every CCButton option for 20 minutes this is the closest I could get it. The first image is the original image and the second in the image in SpriteBuilder.

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the second image, the edges seem jagged a bit and are curving in the wrong direction. Can anyone explain to me why this is happening and how I can fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't checked but CCButton may be using CCSprite9Slice internally which might explain the stretching. Also, there may be tiny discrepancies between Spritebuilder and the actual app, so if you haven't check what it looks like in the app on a device.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Will do. Is there any way to turn off CCSprite9Slice or change the filtering somehow so that it looks likes the first image?

Comment: probably not but again i'm guessing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up subclassing CCSprite and just adding my own touch controls to that. Now it looks great!

Answer (score 2):

I got this settings to work correctly by clicking the "Reset to default size" button. It automatically set the Preferred Size to half the width and height of my original image (since my 'default scaling' is set to '2x' in File->Project Settings).

To keep the button size intact while adding text then set the 'max size' property to the same as 'preferred size'.

Answer (score 1):

`CCButton` uses a `CCSprite9Slice` and you need to set the `preferred size` of the button to solve your problem. If the preferred size matches the image size then the image will not be stretched:

[image]

You also need to take the scaling factor into account. If the you provide the image as a 4x asset, you need to set preferred size to 1/4 of the image size.

Comment: I tried that and it still looks stretched in the corners both on in SpriteBuilder and on the device? Any other workarounds?

Comment: Can you try setting the *Max size* to the same size? If that works for you I will update my answer.

Comment: You need to make sure that you have no title inside the button... sometimes if the title text is bigger, it can stretch the button.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the image try editing it so you don't have to scale it.